# Synching Stomp over Web Sockets in SpringBoot on a Cluster with Redis as a Message Broker

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, stomp

I am working on a SpringBoot web app using web sockets and I have a functional implementation for a single server.

I am researching the best solution for integrating a cluster of servers so that the clients connected to each of the load balanced servers would get the broadcasted messages sent from all servers.

**What is the best practice to connect clustered web socket servers?**

I see references to RabitMQ but since we have Redis already in place I am trying to figure out if Redis will work as a Stomp Message Broker.

Thanks in advance,

Erion

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement this using using existing Redis / Sentinel setup using pub/sub.

Events are sent to the server using SockJS as normal, and then Redis, which then publishes to the subscribers.

I used this SpringBoot reference documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/2.5.4/reference/html/#reference